# Why get data is empty when using curl and regex

Tags: php, html, regex, curl

Please help me check this code. I think my regex wrote has a problem but I don't know how to fix it:

```
function get_data($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$content = get_data('http://ibongda.vn/lich-thi-dau-bong-da.hs');
$regex = '/<div id="zone-schedule-group-by-season">(.*)<\/div>/';
preg_match($regex, $content, $matches);
$table = $matches[1];
print_r($table);
```

Comment: dont parse html with a regular expression

Comment: The bug isn't in your regex, it's in your design. Regex is not the correct tool to parse HTML. I suggest looking at one of 'soup' families of HTML parsers - at a glance http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ looks like a good option.

Comment: I try simpledomhtml but it's very slow. My hosting has php 5.3 so I can't use the newest goutte version. I don't know other way :(

Comment: Using DOM is never slower than RegExp once the input is just DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest don't use regex to parse these. You can use an HTML Parser, `DOMDocument` with xpath in particular.

```
function get_data($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$content = get_data('http://ibongda.vn/lich-thi-dau-bong-da.hs');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // handle errors yourself
$dom->loadHTML($content);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$table_rows = $xpath->query('//div[@id="zone-schedule-group-by-season"]/table/tbody/tr[@class!="bg-gd" and @class!="table-title"]'); // these are the rows of that table

foreach($table_rows as $rows) { // loop each tr
    foreach($rows->childNodes as $td) { // loop each td
        if(trim($td->nodeValue) != '') { // don't show empty td
            echo trim($td->nodeValue) . '<br/>';
        }
    }
    echo '<hr/>';
}
```

Comment: i suggest you link to one of the billion duplicates ;-) In preference to answering

Comment: how do I get html element from $table? I echo $table->item(0)->nodeValue but I'm only get text.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise against using regular expression for this. You should use [**DOM**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for this task.

The problem with your regular expression is running into newline sequences, it will match until the `<` in `</div>`, continuously keep backtracking and fail. Backtracking is what regular expressions do during the course of matching when a match fails. You need to use the `s` (dotall) modifier which forces the dot to match newlines as well.

```
$regex = '~<div id="zone-schedule-group-by-season">(.*?)</div>~s';
```

Comment: I'll follow DOM, many thanks :) I got it :)